# How do I show that $W$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given that $w = (x, 0)$ is the set of points in the plane with ordinate $0$, show that $w$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

Let $W = \{(x, 0) \mid x\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

Then $(0,0)\in W$, which implies that $W\neq\varnothing$.

It is clear that $W\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Moroever, $u = (x_{1},0) + (x_{2},0)\in W$ for every $x_{1},x_{2}\in\mathbb{R}$.

Can someone tell me what should I do after that?

Comment: You need to show that $\alpha w_1+\beta w_2\in W$ for any $w_1,w_2\in W$ and any $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to show that $a u \in W$ for any real number $a$ and any $u$ in $W$.

Answer (score 0):

To show that a subset of a vector space forms a subspace,  you just need to show closure under addition and scalar multiplication.

These can also be combined into one.   That's show $av+w\in S $ for any $v,w\in S $ and $a\in\mathbb F $, where $\mathbb F $ is the base field.